# How can I copy my home directory aliases in docker as ~ doesn't seem to work?

Tags: docker

In my Dockerfile...

I can copy files that I've moved into my the directory I am in, e.g.

```
COPY docker_files/.bash_aliases /root/
```

but how do I refer to my home directory, i.e. "`~`"

```
COPY ~/.bash_aliases /root/
```

as when I use "`~`" I get:

```
Step 5/6 : COPY ~/.bash_aliases /root/
COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder645558599/~/.bash_aliases: no such file or directory
```

I want to avoid hardcoding to my username.
Maybe I should use $USER or $USERNAME not sure

Answer (score 2):

The only files available to Docker when it builds an image are files in the [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description). Typically, this is the directory containing the `Dockerfile` and all of its sub-directories. Also, typically, this would not include your home directory `~`, so it doesn't make sense to copy files from there.

The simplest solution is probably to first copy the files into the directory containing the Dockerfile (outside of the Docker build process), and then use a relative path in your Dockerfile.

---

As a more specific answer to your specific question, Docker doesn't understand `~`, and you could replace it with `/home/mdurrant`. But that does not solve your problem of keeping things user-agnostic. If you did a "pre-build bash script" or similar, you could copy from `~/.bash_aliases` to `./bash_aliases` (or something similar). But in this case, I'd argue that it's a bad practice since this will change the built image depending on who builds it and what files they have.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the other answer, your home directory is likely not included in the build context. As well Docker's `COPY` command only supports wildcards supported by Golangs `filepath.Match` see [here](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match)

As an alternative to `COPY`ing the `bash_aliases` in your Dockerfile I would suggest that, if possible you just mount them as a volume when you run the container.

*i.e:*

`$ docker run -v ~/bash_aliases:/root <image>`

As an aside if you are planning to distribute this Docker image to other team members you could include the volume mount in a docker-compose file.